# "Get Started" button does not appear in welcome screen for FB Messenger bot

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

I followed the solution in this thread and it is still not working 
[how to setup "Get started" button in facebook messenger bot and when to send welcome message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048224/how-to-setup-get-started-button-in-facebook-messenger-bot-and-when-to-send-wel)

I tried both 
graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=xxxxx
and 
graph.facebook.com/v2.6/page_id/thread_settings?access_token=xxxxx
with the raw body

```
{
  "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
  "thread_state":"new_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
  "payload":"USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"

   }
 ]
}
```

The response message is like this

```
  {
  "result": "Successfully added new_thread's CTAs"
 }
```

But the message in welcoming screen just keep displaying "Type a message..."

Please help. This is so frustrating.  The document on FB developer site is not helpful at all 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/get-started-button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution. The "Get Started" button does not appear because I used the users who are not "Tester" for my app ( but the Welcome text appeared that why I confused)

Comment: It already appeared in my case . Welcome text and Get Started button. The test user is not an admin of that page.

Comment: I have created page and we want that when anyone can search our page from Facebook messenger android app "Get started button"  first time visible. I am not able to get success. In my case Thread setting API where should I called ?

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of bugs/issue that seem to affect if the button appears or not once it is finally set using the POST request, this is what I have found.

**You need to delete the conversation on facebook.com chat not messenger.com or mobile App.** Click the little gear thing in the chat window to do this.

Once deleted on fb.com the button will appear the next time you try to chat on fb.com and on messenger.com

The button will not appear on any previously used Android Messenger clients after deleting on fb.com

To make the button appear again on Android Messenger client you need to clear the Messenger data/cache under Android Settings -> Apps , this will also clear your login and you need to login again.

I don't have an iOS device.

Answer (score 4):

As says in documentation.

> The Get Started button is only rendered the first time the user interacts with a the Page on Messenger.

So, if you has interacted with bot, you newer see this button again.

But, there is livehack. You can delete you chat with bot in [web interface](https://www.messenger.com) and add it again.

Note: Some new users on mobile apps may not receive button on old versions apps.

Comment: Even this doesn't solve it for me. I also get a success message, and I'm able to add / delete a greeting message which does show up when I delete and re-create the conversation. But the "get started" button never shows up!

Comment: [Note: Some new users on mobile apps may not receive button on old versions apps.] < How to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think you must register event like image above