# Facebook messenger bot Get Started Button

Tags: javascript, facebook, bots

I'm building my first messenger bot in js and already can receive and reply to messages and send cards with options, but I've already tried everything to setup a get started button but with no success... Here is what I have done for that:

I don't know what i'm doing wrong or where do i have to call the facebookthreadAPI function. Need advice.

**Excerpt from index.js:**

```
function facebookThreadAPI(jsonFile, cmd){
// Start the request
request({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token='+process.env.token,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    form: require(jsonFile)
},
function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Print out the response body
        console.log(cmd+": Updated.");
        console.log(body);
    } else { 
        // TODO: Handle errors
        console.log(cmd+": Failed. Need to handle errors.");
        console.log(body);
    }
});}
```

**Excerpt from fb-get-started-button.json:**

```
{
   "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
   "thread_state":"new_thread",
   "call_to_actions":[
      {
        "payload":"action?POSTBACKHERE"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook now offers a new API for setting up the Get started button with many other features such as the greeting text and persistent menu so instead of using the old thread_setting API use the messenger profile API. For example, using curl

```
    curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ 
      "get_started":{
         "payload":"GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD"
    }
   }' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Replace PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN with your page access token and GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD with any payload you want.
See the complete [tutorial here](https://www.techiediaries.com/messenger-bot-get-started-button/)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/get-started-button) you can find the documentation.

I have tried to execute the example with no results.

> curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
>     "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
>     "thread_state":"new_thread",
>     "call_to_actions":[
>       {
>         "payload":"USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
>       }
>     ]
>   }' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"

My error is:

> Requires pages_messaging permission to manage the object

But my page is not public.

Edit: You can find the solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39225450/2820388). It doesn't work with the page admin

Answer (score 0):

Now, with that new API, I'm trying to set GetStarted button with that request: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "get_started":{
    "payload":"start"}
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=My_Token"`
 and getting `{"result":"success"}`. But that button still doesn't appear in chat. So, I still dont understand, what's the problem here...